# How to find what causes the futex facility to fail?

Tags: c, semaphore, futex

I am trying to synchronize 5 processes, they have to be created from the same father.

I tried inserting 5 waitpids to wait for the child process to end, but the code never reaches D4 and D5.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


void func1(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2);
void func2(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2);
void func3(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2);
void func4(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2);
void func5(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2);

int main() {
    sem_t s1;
    sem_t s2;

    sem_init(&s1, 1, -1);
    sem_init(&s2, 1, -1);

    void (*arr[5])(sem_t, sem_t) = {func1, func2, func3, func4, func5};

    int pid;

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            arr[i](s1, s2);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


void func1(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2) {
    system("echo D1");
    sem_post(&sem1);
}

void func2(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2) {
    system("echo D2");
    sem_post(&sem1);
}

void func3(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2) {
    system("echo D3");
    sem_post(&sem2);
}

void func4(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2) {
    sem_wait(&sem1);
    system("echo D4");
    sem_post(&sem2);
}

void func5(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2) {
   sem_wait(&sem2);
    system("echo D5");
}
```

I expect D4 to be shown after D1 and D2, and D5 to be shown last (D3 in independent from D1,D2,D4). But my code never reaches D4 because the futex facility returns an unexpected error.

Output:

```
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.D1
D2
D3
```

Comment: 1. `int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);`, note the `unsigned`. 2. passing a `sem_t` by value

Comment: regarding statements like: `sem_init(&s1, 1, -1);`  the third parameter must be a unsigned value.  Here is the syntax from the MAN page: ` int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);`

Comment: in function: `main()`, before the statement: `return 0;` there should be a loop, that contains: `while( wait( NULL ) != -1){;} ` So that the parent process does not exit before all the child processes have exited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the semaphores by *value*, which is incorrect, as the `sem_t` variable in each function is a *copy* of the original.  (That's why functions such as `sem_init()`, `sem_post()`, and `sem_wait()` all take *addresses* of the semaphore as an argument.)

You need to pass the semaphores by *address*, so each function operates on the original semaphores:

```
void func1(sem_t *sem1, sem_t *sem2);
void func2(sem_t *sem1, sem_t *sem2);
void func3(sem_t *sem1, sem_t *sem2);
void func4(sem_t *sem1, sem_t *sem2);
void func5(sem_t *sem1, sem_t *sem2);
```

and

```
void (*arr[5])(sem_t *, sem_t *) = {func1, func2, func3, func4, func5};
```

And call the function as:

```
        arr[i](&s1, &s2);
```

The functions should then take the form:

```
void func1(sem_t *sem1, sem_t *sem2) {
    system("echo D1");
    sem_post(sem1);
}
```

Note that the address passed to `func1()` is passed directly to `sem_post()`.

**Edit:**

As others have noted, you're initializing the semaphores incorrectly.  You can't initialize a semaphore to a negative value.

**Proper shared semaphores**

As noted in the comments, the semphores aren't in memory shared between the multiple processes.

One way to put the semphores in shared memory is to use `mmap()`:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
    ...
    // map a 4k page of shared memory (assumes a sem_t is small
    // enough to fit at least two)
    void *sharedMem = mmap( 0, 4 * 1024, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0 );

    // use the mmap()'d memory as shared semphores
    sem_t *semArray = ( sem_t * ) sharedMem;

    // initialize the semaphores
    sem_init( &( semArray[ 0 ] ), 1, 0 );
    sem_init( &( semArray[ 1 ] ), 1, 0 );
```

The calling code becomes

```
    arr[i](&( semArray[ 0 ] ), &( semArray[ 1 ] ));
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand my fault but unfortunately this isn't what causes the error. The problem occurs because I initialize my semaphores with negative value. I have to find a workaround for this, as I am obliged to use no more than 2 semaphores.

Edit for your edit: exactly.

Comment: @AQUATH Passing-by-value is an issue, too.  If you pass-by-value, the semaphore a functions waits on or posts to might not be the same as the one used by another process.  It *might* "work" on some implementations (for example, if `sem_t` is implemented as a pointer to an implementation-defined object), but it can't be counted on.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Pretty sure the pass-by-value "works" because the semaphores are bogus anyway, considering they are not allocated in shared memory.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Yes indeed.
I changed my semaphores initialization to 0 and added a second wait signal on func4 and func5 but they are never called.

Comment: @EOF That too.  I missed that, and it would need to be addressed to create fully-working code.

Comment: I did some basic printf-debugging, the problem is that both func1 and func2 increase s1 to 1, locally, therefore s1 is never 2 and "D4" is never printed. Same thing applies to func5.

Answer (score -1):

So, there were 2 small changes to be made in that code.

1. First you need to initialize the semaphores correctly. `sem_init(&s1, 1, 1);` instead of `sem_init(&s1, 1, -1);`
2. Your parent process needs to wait for all the child processes to exit, before it itself exits. Hence the `wait(NULL);` in the main before the program ends.

.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


void func1(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2);
void func2(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2);
void func3(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2);
void func4(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2);
void func5(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2);

int main() {
    sem_t s1;
    sem_t s2;

    sem_init(&s1, 1, 1);
    sem_init(&s2, 1, 1);

    void (*arr[5])(sem_t, sem_t) = {func1, func2, func3, func4, func5};

    pid_t child_pid, wpid;
    int status;

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        child_pid = fork();
        if (child_pid == 0) {
            arr[i](s1, s2);
            // break;
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    wait(NULL);
    // while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0);
    return 0;
}


void func1(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2) {
    system("echo D1");
    sem_post(&sem1);
}

void func2(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2) {
    system("echo D2");
    sem_post(&sem1);
}

void func3(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2) {
    system("echo D3");
    sem_post(&sem2);
}

void func4(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2) {
    sem_wait(&sem1);
    system("echo D4");
    sem_post(&sem2);
}

void func5(sem_t sem1, sem_t sem2) {
   sem_wait(&sem2);
    system("echo D5");
}
```

You can run and check here. [oneline code](https://onlinegdb.com/rk_IbbWZV)